# Passing Value from Bootstrap Datepicker to C# Datetimeoffset Nullable type using javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a **Bootstrap datepicker** in my View. I have set one of my model variable to        **`public DateTimeOffset? expiryDate { get; set; }`** 
The Expiry date is an Optional field .So it's the User who uses the application decides whether to set an expiry date or not during a process. by using `$('#datepickerid').val()` i can get the current value from Datepicker and i need to send it to the controller via an ajax call.
I use `var expirydate = $("#datepickerid").val();` can i use this value via the ajax call ?

Comment: *can i use this value via the ajax call ?* - Instead pass it and ask if that does not work. Because in later case you will at least be able to tell the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `var expirydate = $("#datepickerid").val()' in ajax call.

For demo ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3v1ZNR)), I have created a property in Model as

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTimeOffset? ExpiryDate { get; set; }
```

And rendered input as :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpiryDate, new {@class="form-control"})
```

on click of button press, following ajax call is made :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="YourAction", controller="YourController"})',
    data: {datetimeOffset: $('#ExpiryDate').val()},     type: 'POST',                                   success: function(resp) {
    <<Your code>>
}});
```

I have created [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3v1ZNR) dotnet fiddle to demonstrate your ask. Please have a look into it.

Comment: I tried your method but don't know why i am getting null value in controller

Comment: Have you checked the fiddle?

Comment: yup, tried the same i believe . i tried `$('#expiry').val();` to get date value. before ajax post i made an alert and the value is showing in alert but not getting it in controller.

Comment: can you post your js ajax call.

Comment: `$.ajax({  url: "/Controller/Action",                                                         data: JSON.stringify({"ExpiryDate": $("#expiry").val() }),
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                async: false,
                success: function (x){if (x == 0) { swal("Successfully send"); }
                },
                error: function (e)
                {
                 
                    alert(e.error);
                }`This is my ajax post. Found any bugs ???

Comment: I'm gonna take a swing at this and say it has something to do with your controller model binding.  Inspect the actual post data in the Request.Form and see if the values are there. Just realized this is an ancient question.  I'll leave my comment in case it helps someone.